# How to format protobuf file more nicely using clang-format?

Tags: protocol-buffers, clang-format

I am formatting my porotbuf file nicely, here is a example:

```
message StealCache {
    string   CurStealTargetUID          = 1;
    uint32   CurStealMoney              = 2;
    repeated TargetList TargetLists     = 3;
    uint32              Count           = 4;
    uint32              Timestamp       = 5;
    StealTreasureBox    StealBox        = 6;
    uint32              ExtraStealMoney = 7;
}
```

The current clang-format style tag is:

```
{BasedOnStyle: Google, 
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, 
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true, 
ColumnLimit: 0, 
IndentWidth: 4}
```

But what I want is like this:

```
message StealCache {
    string              CurStealTargetUID   = 1;
    uint32              CurStealMoney       = 2;
    repeated TargetList TargetLists         = 3;
    uint32              Count               = 4;
    uint32              Timestamp           = 5;
    StealTreasureBox    StealBox            = 6;
    uint32              ExtraStealMoney     = 7;
}
```

How could I modify my clang-format style?

Comment: Which version of clang-format are you using? I am able to get the desired output with your style tag.

Comment: @RahulSreeram llvm 9.0. Same tag?

Comment: yes. I am using the same version and used the style tag you have specified.

Comment: @RahulSreeram So weird, are your sure your have that "repeated" line? It will be so nice if you could show me your tag and proto file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved when llvm(9.0.0) upgraded.